# cryptoJS aes encode data NOT match with java code

Tags: java, cryptojs

```
var get = function(a) {
    var b = CryptoJS.MD5('contentWindowHig');
    var c = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(b);
    var d = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('contentDocuments');
    var e = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(a, c, {
        iv: d,
        mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC
        pad: CryptoJS.pad.ZeroPadding
    });
    return e.toString()
}
}
```

## java output is not the same

input plain text: 8d3fj5T7lPMjMfMTyzdbl6Aq95zSUrmuChBFf/ex3lF23jHweq9ABJmEbd7+4z5DmjmhvTVyXWoeoFWCv6xCPFw7CAx7n9RZ9x9fOVrY3Cy+Nm1TAThsjgOjjK+M1S3XIim39NiRp55ai/dm2+E+NzRGPN0wW1bc9Q

js output data:

a: 8d3fj5T7lPMjMfMTyzdbl6Aq95zSUrmuChBFf/ex3lF23jHweq9ABJmEbd7+4z5DmjmhvTVyXWoeoFWCv6xCPFw7CAx7n9RZ9x9fOVrY3Cy+Nm1TAThsjgOjjK+M1S3XIim39NiRp55ai/dm2+E+NzRGPN0wW1bc9Q

b: a165f267f74aba5ded7563ebae2c5ac0

c: 6131363566323637663734616261356465643735363365626165326335616330

d: 636f6e74656e74446f63756d656e7473

e(output): YzYv1oDPuHMyvtt8dgHUOdKaTev3rDtDXu9O%2BBlnCt4X118BroqK7nDjc%2Bo6cb6aoik6KAvIhZwENjkmrMvF26xhhWATh0TrlK0ZWPotNWI9mXWW1FgZtRrFkQGn6%2F4BWY8D%2BAfLxePup4rAw%2BekHjpkFsSZcY6rlL37uUKU%2F6OTdN4rrjG3FOEmN8yDZ9sMNAXu%2FdmAqgFRJ77gvWjgKZEXvhqYqaH1Ukb9eZYMRAE%3D

## base64 utf-8 aes iv key confused me...

java output data:

b: a165f267f74aba5ded7563ebae2c5ac0

c: 6131363566323637663734616261356465643735363365626165326335616330

d: 636F6E74656E74446F63756D656E7473

enc_data: fPkNBugoCDHtBLO4tv9VcfGNCWxbqdWryrOWPXrsqN2I0IzNfTN+Smh5PQX5fKsGuHtGWFv7Lryh
jEgOSUJNskH/JD1agfWfzDClSWA7eF4bpKmTg3ch8mrHHI7nwDm4t6jQEeCfDGcQ3Sa8s0UPipOR
wcOTdGVl7RmgJ5gIERQ45m34fm8tveMYrXyTgvDKbvqO7toqshcg6IOxNgB5OCr/DH4xQibnYPnk
0Z4EBy8=

encoded_str: fPkNBugoCDHtBLO4tv9VcfGNCWxbqdWryrOWPXrsqN2I0IzNfTN%2BSmh5PQX5fKsGuHtGWFv7Lryh%0D%0AjEgOSUJNskH%2FJD1agfWfzDClSWA7eF4bpKmTg3ch8mrHHI7nwDm4t6jQEeCfDGcQ3Sa8s0UPipOR%0D%0AwcOTdGVl7RmgJ5gIERQ45m34fm8tveMYrXyTgvDKbvqO7toqshcg6IOxNgB5OCr%2FDH4xQibnYPnk%0D%0A0Z4EBy8%3D

```
import com.pplive.common.util.LogUtil;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;

import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            // key: 8d3fj5T7lPMjMfMTyzdbl6Aq95zSUrmuChBFf/ex3lF23jHweq9ABJmEbd7+4z5DmjmhvTVyXWoeoFWCv6xCPFw7CAx7n9RZ9x9fOVrY3Cy+Nm1TAThsjgOjjK+M1S3XIim39NiRp55ai/dm2+E+NzRGPN0wW1bc9Q
            // b: a165f267f74aba5ded7563ebae2c5ac0
            // c: 6131363566323637663734616261356465643735363365626165326335616330
            // d: 636f6e74656e74446f63756d656e7473
            //ss: YzYv1oDPuHMyvtt8dgHUOdKaTev3rDtDXu9O%2BBlnCt4X118BroqK7nDjc%2Bo6cb6aoik6KAvIhZwENjkmrMvF26xhhWATh0TrlK0ZWPotNWI9mXWW1FgZtRrFkQGn6%2F4BWY8D%2BAfLxePup4rAw%2BekHjpkFsSZcY6rlL37uUKU%2F6OTdN4rrjG3FOEmN8yDZ9sMNAXu%2FdmAqgFRJ77gvWjgKZEXvhqYqaH1Ukb9eZYMRAE%3D

            //int end = html.indexOf("\")", start);
            //String plaintext = html.substring(start + "encodeURIComponent(get(\"".length(), end);
            String plaintext = "8d3fj5T7lPMjMfMTyzdbl6Aq95zSUrmuChBFf/ex3lF23jHweq9ABJmEbd7+4z5DmjmhvTVyXWoeoFWCv6xCPFw7CAx7n9RZ9x9fOVrY3Cy+Nm1TAThsjgOjjK+M1S3XIim39NiRp55ai/dm2+E+NzRGPN0wW1bc9Q";
            System.out.println("plaintext: " + plaintext);

            try {
                String b = EncoderByMd5("contentWindowHig");
                System.out.println("b: " + b);

                String c = byteToHexString(b.getBytes("utf-8"));
                System.out.println("c: " + c);

                String d = byteToHexString("contentDocuments".getBytes("utf-8"));
                System.out.println("d: " + d);

                String enc_data = AES_CBC_Encrypt_nopadding(
                        plaintext.getBytes("utf-8"),
                        b.getBytes(),
                        "contentDocuments".getBytes());
                System.out.println("enc_data: " + enc_data);

                String encoded_str = URLEncoder.encode(enc_data, "utf-8");
                System.out.println("encoded_str: " + encoded_str);
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
}
        public static String AES_CBC_Encrypt_nopadding(byte[] content, byte[] keyBytes, byte[] iv){

                try{
                    KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
                    keyGenerator.init(128, new SecureRandom(keyBytes));
                    SecretKey key = keyGenerator.generateKey();
                    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
                    int blockSize = cipher.getBlockSize();
                    // process plain text
                    int plaintextLength = content.length;
                    if (plaintextLength % blockSize != 0) {
                        plaintextLength = plaintextLength + (blockSize - (plaintextLength % blockSize));
                    }
                    byte[] plaintext = new byte[plaintextLength];
                    System.arraycopy(content, 0, plaintext, 0, content.length);
                    for (int i=content.length;i<plaintextLength;i++) {
                        plaintext[i] = (byte)0;
                    }
                    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
                    byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(plaintext);
                    BASE64Encoder base64en = new BASE64Encoder();
                    return base64en.encode(encrypted);
                }catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    System.out.println("exception:"+e.toString());
                }
                return null;
            }
    public static String EncoderByMd5(String str) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
            MessageDigest md5=MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            md5.update(str.getBytes());
            return new BigInteger(1, md5.digest()).toString(16);
        }

    public static String AES_CBC_Decrypt(byte[] content, byte[] keyBytes, byte[] iv){

            try{
                KeyGenerator keyGenerator=KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
                keyGenerator.init(128, new SecureRandom(keyBytes));//key长可设为128，192，256位，这里只能设为128
                SecretKey key=keyGenerator.generateKey();
                Cipher cipher=Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
                cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
                byte[] result = cipher.doFinal(content);
                BASE64Encoder base64en = new BASE64Encoder();
                return base64en.encode(result);
            }catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                System.out.println("exception:"+e.toString());
            }
            return null;
        }

    //Converting a string of hex character to bytes
        public static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String s) {
            int len = s.length();
            byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
            for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2){
                data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
                        + Character.digit(s.charAt(i+1), 16));
            }
            return data;
        }

        public static String byteToHexString(byte[] bytes) {
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer(bytes.length);
            String sTemp;
            for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
                sTemp = Integer.toHexString(0xFF & bytes[i]);
                if (sTemp.length() < 2)
                    sb.append(0);
                sb.append(sTemp.toUpperCase());
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }
```

Comment: So you're saying that code you *have* posted gives a different result to code you *haven't* posted. Please post the Java code...

Comment: Although using the result of an MD5 hash *as if it were UTF-8 text* is worrying... unless CryptoJS.MD5 actually returns a string?

Comment: java code had updated. CryptoJs implement make me confused.

Comment: or somone can just tell me how to convert 4 lines js code to THE corrent java version code.Thx.

Comment: Well now we don't know what `EncoderByMd5` does. (I'd strongly urge you to start following Java naming conventions, too.) If the URL encoding part isn't relevant, strip it out of your example. Declare that your `main` method can throw `Exception` and you don't need the try/catch either. Aim for a *minimal* (but complete) example.

Comment: You also appear to be trying some diagnostics for b, c and d - but you haven't shown the output of those, or what they are for the JS version. This is all diagnostic work you should be doing to find out the first point at which there's a difference.

Comment: Okay, so now that you've seen that `a`, `b` and `c` are the same (although I would *strongly* advise against using BigInteger like that, along with `String.getBytes()` without an encoding) you can reduce your code to hard-code those values. The more you can do to reduce the code, the clearer it will be where the problem is. (Why are you including `AES_CBC_Decrypt` when you never call it, for example?)

Comment: because the output is always NOT the same.just try. And I found that "NO-PADDING" make NO diffrence to output ?

Comment: The output for the *last* part may not be the same, but you've shown the output for b, c and d (not a, sorry) - so hardcode those. The idea is to get to the *absolute minimum* code required to show the problem. This is part of every day diagnostics...

Answer (score -1):

so easy .

js convert to java

```
// var b = CryptoJS.MD5('contentWindowHig');

String b = org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils.md5Hex("contentWindowHig");

// var c = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(b);

byte[] c = b.getByte("UTF-8");

// var d = CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse('contentDocuments');

byte[] d = "contentDocuments".getByte("UTF-8");

  /* var e = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(a, c, {
      iv: d,
      mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC
      pad: CryptoJS.pad.ZeroPadding
  }); 
  return e.toString()
  */


Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(c, "AES"), new IvParameterSpec(d));

Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(a.getBytes("utf-8")));
```

a is encrypt str